# Custom Location for Composite Components in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I am attempting to serve composite components from a database and I am wondering if anyone knows if this is possible.  I am currently doing this with regular xhtml/facelets pages via a custom javax.faces.view.facelets.ResourceResolver.  Is there anything similar for composite components?  I have a CMS system that allows the users to modify the pages stored in a database, but currently the only thing that they can't modify if composite components because as far as I know they can only be served from the resources/components directory is that correct?  If I could even change this location to outside of my context this would help.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.